# Deprecated Inventory object from google play billing library 1.0?

Tags: android, android-billing, play-billing-library

1. In the previous library as we were getting Inventory object, how can we get it from billing library version 1.0?
2. How can we get developer payload, which we are getting in Purchase object?

For reference :

```
public void onQueryInventoryFinished(IabResult result, Inventory inventory) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Query inventory finished.");
}
```

Note : I am referencing from the library code - https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-billing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As with the older version of google play billing library, inventory object contains devloperPayload field which is useful to verify user authenticity. But now google devs suggested changing the approach, and user verification with developerPayload has to be handled on the own application/server side, instead of google play billing response.
Here is the link for more details regarding this issue: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/63381481